# Fast web search selected text in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I know how to web search selected text in Firefox (select, right-click, find the Search For menu option, release), but since I use that function up to dozens of times a day, I find it frustratingly slow.

Is there a faster way? Something like CTRL double click a word, or select a phrase, then press 's'?

Another option would be to assign a hot key to the Search For menu item. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QuickDrag](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quickdrag/) is a simple but superb addon. It extends the function of the drag-and-drop mouse gesture so that it can be used to load URLs, **do a web search of selected text** on a page, or save an image on a page. Use it, and you'll like it.

[image]

I suggest using the following settings:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to SuperUser. You can set this as the accepted answer by marking the tick mark on the left.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. Could not initially find this Ajaxy goodness. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try [Search selected](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/searchselected/?src=search). [Selected search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selected-search/?src=search) is the one I use.